# What is wrong with this query? I am not getting correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

What is wrong with this query, please let me know.
From the inner query I want to select top 1 group by on the basis of EventID.

Please suggest what to do.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
    (
    SELECT E.EventID, ETD.EventName, ED.EventDate FROM 
    [3rdi_EventDates] AS ED inner join [3rdi_Events] as E on ED.EventID=E.EventID 
    inner join [3rdi_EventTypeDetails] as ETD on E.EventTypeId=ETD.EventTypeId
    WHERE E.EventID in
    (
    select EventId from [3rdi_Events] WHERE
    EventID IN (select distinct EventId from [3rdi_EventDates] where EventDate Between '2/9/2011' and '3/11/2012')
    ) ORDER BY ETD.EventName, ED.EventDate  
    ) AS temp Group by EventID
```

Comment: Do you get results in the inner query?

Comment: Even first i thought to use distinct but in that case i have to loose the date field but i cant loose any field.

Comment: If you provide some sample data for each of the tables I should be able to knock it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one record per EventID, in which case, use Row_Number() and partitioning.

Your two levels of subquery are also not needed, the inner joins involve both tables in the subqueries so you can filter directly in the main query.

The last point to make is that date literals are best written using YYYYMMDD to be robust against any regional or dateformat settings.

```
SELECT EventID, EventName, EventDate
FROM (
    SELECT E.EventID, ETD.EventName, ED.EventDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (
            partition by E.EventID 
            ORDER BY ETD.EventName, ED.EventDate) RowNum
    FROM [3rdi_EventDates] AS ED
    inner join [3rdi_Events] as E on ED.EventID=E.EventID 
    inner join [3rdi_EventTypeDetails] as ETD on E.EventTypeId=ETD.EventTypeId
    where ED.EventDate Between '20110209' and '20120311'
    ) AS temp
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: It works, but whats wrong with my query, would you please elaborate me a little.

Comment: Your query has a single TOP 1 across the entire resultset, so you get 1 record - that's it. Also, you had `ORDER BY ETD.EventName, ED.EventDate  ` hanging in a subquery. ORDERing in sub queries don't mean anything, unless you also add TOP `to the same subquery` to get `top x ordered by`.

Comment: @Novice like I said, you have a single TOP 1 at the beginning of the query. That makes the entire query return only 1 row. You either have to use a complicated `CROSS APPLY`, or the code shown above.

Comment: @ cyberkiwi: but in my case it was not returning even a single row.

Comment: @Novice do you mean that it ran with 0 records, or that there was an error? You have an ORDER by in the inner query which should have caused a syntax error.

Comment: Yes u are true, it run with error. Thats what i want to know, why so?

Comment: Because it does not make sense to ORDER BY in an inner query. The results are further processed outside (after the subquery), so even if it were allowed, the order is `not preserved`. So rather than mislead you, it is simply not allowed. **Unless** you add a `TOP X` in the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM  (
    SELECT E.EventID, ETD.EventName, ED.EventDate FROM 
    [3rdi_EventDates] AS ED inner join [3rdi_Events] as E on ED.EventID=E.EventID 
    inner join [3rdi_EventTypeDetails] as ETD on E.EventTypeId=ETD.EventTypeId
    WHERE ED.EventDate > Convert(Datetime,'2/9/2011') and ED.EventDate < Convert(Datetime,'3/11/2012')
    ORDER BY ETD.EventName, ED.EventDate)
```

Comment: not working giving error "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
"